# Como crear un trigger para que no borre un registro si este contiene determinadas caracteristicas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Es decir, crear un trigger que me impida eliminar un registro de la tabla 'persona', pero solo si el nombre contiene los siguientes caracteres: 'JUAN' e imprimir el mensaje de que no se puede eliminar

```
CREATE TRIGGER borrar
ON PERSONA
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @NOMBRE VARCHAR(30)
SELECT @NOMBRE = D.NOMBRE 
FROM PERSONA P INNER JOIN DELETED D 
ON P.ID_PER=D.ID_PER
IF (@NOMBRE LIKE '%JUAN%')
BEGIN
PRINT 'NO ES POSIBLE ELIMINAR'
END
ELSE
DELETE FROM PERSONA WHERE NOMBRE=@NOMBRE
GO
```

Comment: que probaste hasta ahora?

Comment: @gbianchi eso es lo que probe, aunque ya me han dado una mejor solucion, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es mas o menos así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Ejemplo ON persona
    FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM DELETED WHERE CHARINDEX('JUAN', NOMBRE) > 0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ( 'No se puede eliminar una persona con el nombre Juan',  16, 10)
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ha funcionado y me ha sido de gran ayuda.